# (C++) Pointers to Pointers of objects in different classes

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, visual-c++, pointer-to-member

everyone. I'm working on a final project for school and it's coming along great, but I've run into a bit of a problem with trying to use a pointer to a pointer. I'll do my best to explain the problem below:

So I have a class called Player that sort of looks like this:

```
class Player
{
    Player();
    int health;
    void adjustHealth(int);
};

Player::Player()
{
    health = 40;
}

void Player::adjustHealth(int adjust)
{
    health += adjust;
}
```

I have another class called Shelter, that include "Player.h" and looks a little like this:

```
class Shelter
{
    Shelter();
    Player* player;     // Create a pointer to Player class.
};
```

In the Shelter header file, I have the following in my default constructor:

```
Shelter::Shelter()
{
    ...Other code here.
    player = new Player();
}
```

In the Shelter header file, I use this new player for things like:

```
 player->adjustHealth(-1);  // Subtract one health from the player.
```

Which works great.

The problem I'm facing is with creating another class called Church, that is in a separate header file and acts as a separate location in the game. I want Church to use the same player that Shelter does, so it has all of the same stats, etc, rather than creating a new player in Church (which is what I did in Shelter.h).

Right now, I have something like:

```
class Church
{
Church();
Shelter **cplayer; // This is supposed to be the pointer to the pointer.
};
```

The default constructor is where I'm having my problem. I want to use the same player from Shelter, not create a new player like I did in Shelter.

```
Church::Church
{
    What should I do here?
}
```

I've tried a number of things, but I can't quite get it working. Eventually I want to be able to do something like this:

```
   player->adjustHealth(-1);    // Subtract one health from the player.
```

Only in Church, so that player's stats, like health, are adjusted no matter which location they are in.

I hope my question makes sense. If not, I can try to clarify better. Anyway, thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you want `player` to be a global variable instead of being inside a class.

Comment: What you "should do here" is figure out how to find the pointer you need. Since only you have the full access to the code, and knows where each object is accessible from, only you have all the information needed to answer your question.

Comment: I don't get why you need a pointer to a pointer. Do you want to have two objects of type `Shelter` and `Church` have a pointer pointing to the same `Player` object?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'm unable to use global variables for this project, but I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: @FeiXiang Yes. Think of the Shelter and the Church as different locations. I want to be able to use the same Player object for both, so that if stat changes happen in either location, it's updated in both. If that makes sense.

Comment: Then you probably want to give a pointer to the constructor of `Shelter` and `Church` pointing to the `Player` object. No need for a pointer to pointer.

Comment: @TristanLuisSantiago If you are unable to use global variables for some reason, I'd make a `Game` class, give all the locations a pointer to the `Game` (by making it a parameter of their constructors) and put the player pointer in the Game class. (As well as all the random other stuff that *would* be global if you were able to use globals)

Comment: You shouldn't use a pointer to pointer for that kind of thing. You should update the pointer in both, and contain the pointer elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you all. I'll try some of these and see how they work.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I'm facing is with creating another class called Church, that is in a separate header file and acts as a separate location in the game. I want Church to use the same player that Shelter does, so it has all of the same stats, etc, rather than creating a new player in Church

This sounds like an ideal situation to use `std::shared_ptr`.

```
class Shelter
{
    Shelter();
    std::shared_ptr<Player> player;     // Create a pointer to Player class.

    // Provide a public accessor
    public:
       std::shared_Ptr<Player> getPlayer() const { return player; }
};
```

and

```
class Church
{
    Church(std::shared_ptr<Player> pl) : player(pl) {}
    std::shared_ptr<Player> player;

    // You haven't explained in your post why you need this.
    // Maybe you don't need it.
    // Shelter** shelter;
};
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. The Church class is currently functioning as a separate location. So the Shelter is one and the Church is another. When the player is at the Shelter, he moves around the map doing things, collecting items, etc. The player can lose or recover health while doing those things. Then there comes a point in the game where the player can leave the Shelter and go to the Church (and other locations eventually). I want to be able to use that same player from Shelter only in Church. So if the player loses 5 health in the Shelter, when he goes to the Church, he has 35 health.

Comment: @TristanLuisSantiago, all of that can be supported using a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Thanks, @R Sahu. I'll definitely give them a shot! I appreciate the help!